# Python run console or GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line, exe

Is it possible to make a python script that run the function A if you start it from command-line and the function B if you start it by double-click ? Like in C++ start the ncurses if command-line otherwise start the SFML.

I tried to use isatty or an argument if run from command-line, but it isn't convenient when creating an executable for Windows to display a black console for your script.

Comment: What are you double-clicking to run the python script?

Comment: The .py or .pyw (i want my .pyw to run in command-line somehow).

Comment: so you don't want it to run the GUI if you start from console? If that's the case you could use an argument with argparse or argv and a --nogui argument and check if thats not there to run form gui.

Comment: It works but I can't print in the console when I "compile" it with `pyinstaller --windowed`

Comment: ahh so you're using pyinstaller to make a windows gui exe?

Comment: this reddit post may help you: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6b8s7c/will_the_effects_of_print_statements_be_visible/

Comment: Yes but I want to also be able to run it in command-line at the same time. Maybe it's impossible and I try to make things complicated for nothing ^^'